# FIWARE Orion Context Broker: How do I search for entities that are near a coordinate?

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm using Orion Context Broker v1.7 and have been trying to list entities that are within 1000 meters from certain coordinates using GET on Postman:

```
/v2/entities?georel=near&maxDistance=1000&geometry=point&coords=52.3766134;4.8971626
```

The response I get is:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "Invalid query: georel /near/ without either minDistance nor maxDistance"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a syntax error in your query. From [NGSIv2 specification](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/) section "Geographical Queries":

```
georel=near;maxDistance:1000&geometry=point&coords=-40.4,-3.5
```

So your query should be:

```
GET /v2/entities?georel=near;maxDistance:1000&geometry=point&coords=52.3766134;4.8971626
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last coordinate values be separated by , and not ; ?

Comment: Not sure of the syntax rigth now... Just try both and tell us the right one ;)

Comment: Tested. It should be separated by commas.